# Bluetooth serial data connect from arduino Uno R4 Wifi to Android phone

Tags: android, c, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno

I use arduino uno R3 with bluetooth HC-06 and the following the sample code to controll a 2wheel car:

```
char val;
void setup() 
{  
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 10 set as output Pin
pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 11 set as output Pin
pinMode(11, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 12 set as output Pin
pinMode(12, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 13 set as output Pin
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
  val = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(val);
  }

  if( val == 'F') // Forward
    {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);  
    }
.....
```

It works. I am trying to do the same with uno R4 wifi but I have the problem in pairing to bluetooth in android phone. I need help to initialize the built in bluetooth on the new uno R4.